# Set UINavigationBar title color when composing an email

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I have a ViewController which contains a WebView. When I click on an email link (mailto:) in the WebView, iOS will push a ViewController that allows the user to compose an email. The title in the NavigationBar of this controller has black text, and I can't find a way to change the color. I was able to change the background color of the NavigationBar, as well as the button text color, but not the title color.

I am coding this app in Xamarin (C#), but I should be able to translate Swift/Objective C code, if provided as a solution.

In my App Delegate, I set some theme defaults.

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;
UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Red;
UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = false;
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.White;
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes()
{
    TextColor = UIColor.White           
});

UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes.ForegroundColor = UIColor.White;
UIButton.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(UINavigationBar)).TintColor = UIColor.White;
```

I also set `this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Black;` in each of my ViewControllers. I am assuming this is where the problem is. I am unable to set the BarStyle in the compose email view controller, and it doesn't appear to use the global appearance value.

Comment: Are you using `MFMailComposeViewController` for this?

Comment: I am not presenting the ViewController myself, the WebView handles the email links, and automatically presents the compose email ViewController. From what I have read, it's probably a MFMailComposeViewController, but I am not instantiating it myself.

Comment: As far as I know, mailto: results in opening of the Mail app, which then obviously means you can't do anything regarding that. Please check if that is the case.

Comment: This is not the case, if I change the line `UIButton.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(typeof(UINavigationBar)).TintColor = UIColor.White;` to a different color, the NavBar buttons will change to the new color. It's just the Title color that I am unable to change.

Comment: @Dave Hi, which do you want to change , text color or bar color ?

Comment: Text color. I am already able to change the bar color.

Comment: @Dave Okey, I have updated answer for changing Text color. If be helpful , thanks for marking in advance .

Comment: Thanks @JuniorJiang-MSFT, I am just on holiday this week, but I will try this as soon as I am back in the office. If it works, I'll mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Dave Good, Enjoy the holiday.

Answer (score 0):

In **Xamarin.IOS :**

If want to change navigation bar text color , coding as bellow:

```
UIStringAttributes uIStringAttributes = new UIStringAttributes();
uIStringAttributes.ForegroundColor = UIColor.YouWantColor; //such as UIColor.Green
NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = uIStringAttributes;
```

[image]

If want to change navigation bar and status bar , coding as bellow:

```
NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.YouWantColor;
// Color you want, such as UIColor.Green
```

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me.

I'm setting up my appearance defaults in my AppDelegate. If I use this code, all of the titles in my app will have the selected color *except* for the compose email page. The title on that page remains black.

Comment: @Dave Yeah ,  using code in special Controller, not write in AppDeleage .

Comment: I don't have access to the controller. The Compose email controller is automatically presented when clicking on a "mailto" link. I did not make the controller, it's built into the platform.

Comment: @Dave Got it , if controller from a "mailto" link then now can do nothing with it .

Comment: I can customize all of the styling *except* the color of the title text. I was hoping there was a workaround.

Comment: @Dave Okey, if find the solution ,will share here.